# Auto fit iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a difficulty on design a web page layout.
This is my layout structure.

```
<style>
#left
{
  float:left;
  width:600px;
  min-height:400px;
}

#right
{
  float:right;
  width:200px;
  min-height:400px;
}
</style>
<body>
<center>
<div id="page">
<div id="left">
<iframe />
</div>
<div id="right">right panel</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
</center>
</div>
</body>
```

1. How can i make the both left & right div grow when the right div's child increase more than the min height?
2. How can i make the both left & right div grow when the content in the iframe is longer than the min height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't with basic HTML/CSS, jQuery however has the following function: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

I would imagine that you could get the size of one div and resize the other to the same.

^_^